# VBA conditional line formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I have a chart with many series. There is a Series Collection titled ("Upper Limit"). If any other series in the chart crosses over that threshold, it needs to be changed to a dotted line. I get a run time error 438 when I run this code

```
Sub dottedlines()


Dim mySrs As Series
Dim nPts As Long
Dim d As DataLabel
Dim i As Integer
Dim srs As SeriesCollection

i = 1

For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection

If mySrs.Points(i + 1).Value > srs("Upper Limit").Points(i + 1).Value Then

With mySrs.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .DashStyle = msoLineSysDash
        .Weight = 1.25
End With

i = i + 1

End If

Next mySrs

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this something you're able to do manually? Just curious, as the 438 error suggests that's not supported behavior.

Comment: This needs to be applied to a large number of charts, so ideally it would be automated